# Is there any tool that can help me analyze the class structure of my objective-c project?

Tags: ios, class, import, structure

I got a terrible legacy IOS project recently. I want to clear those redundant classes that will not be executed in the whole project anymore. It there any tool that can help me doing this?

What I image is there can have some tools help me locate those redundant #import like Eclipse do. After clear those unused #import, there can be some tool that help me analyze the relationship between each class. Finally, I can see which block of classes is never used in the whole project and I can delete them safely.

But unfortunately I can't find anything useful... maybe I'm searching in the wrong direction. Does anyone have a clue? please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/). 
It can build dependency charts from your Xcode project.